# My storage chips work fine for a while then they say the memory is full and cannot be used or reformatted

Tags: data-transfer

I am having a problem with the storage chips we're using. They work fine for a while and then they just say the memory is full even though I've deleted every file every time I upload them to my computer.
We've been using 16GB chips for the wild life camera and it doesn't take too long for this to happen.
Today, however, my64GB chip did the same thing in my camera that I'm using to take videos every day of the baby birds.
When I tried to reformat the disk, the chip would not show up on the side bar to choose for anything.
Then I looked in help online on how to reformat removable disks on a Mac.
These directions indicate that there could be a limit on how many times you can write over an erased file.
I don't know what else would cause this problem.

Comment: *"I am having a problem with the storage chips ..."* -- Referring to a storage device by its internal components is like naming foods by their ingredients, e.g. "I like flour" instead of saying cookies and cake.  IOW use the proper name, e.g. Compact Flash, or SD card, or USB flash drive etc.

Answer (score 0):

Removable media fail much more often than drives and memory in a computer. The stress of plugging and unplugging in time creates physical damage on the circuit board where the chips connect, and then the removable media fails. You will notice removable media have much shorter warranties than drives and memory within a computer.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense to me.

Comment: You can click on the checkmark to the left of the answer to accept an answer, to show others it solved the problem for you, and the up arrowhead to show the information was useful. This helps others who have the same problem.